# E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: java, database, mongodb, jdbc

I am trying to insert documents into mongodb from java. First record is being inserted and it is showing the error as 'E11000 duplicate key error'. I even tried to make the documents unique. Still I am getting the same error. Here I provide the screen shot of the same.

Mongodb version: v 3.4.10

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Could you please share your code of entity class and method with call `[your_repo].save(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sowmyasurampalli, **E11000** it's a mongodb code error that means that some entry is duplicated, when you use a field as unique field(in you case _id is default set to unique), you should enter distinct documents _ids else this error 'll be thrown, so in your app you need also to catch that error to inform the user that the entry was duplicated.
Also, if you are sure that the docs that you're inserting have unique ids, just remove your collection from the DB because it contains the inserted documents from the previous insertion!

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped the collection and everything started working fine after that

1.) Just delete the database using the command : db.dropDatabase();

(don't find the above step aggressive)

2.) Create new db : use dbname

3.)Restart the server : npm start

Note : ( Dropped indexes or db will be rebuilt once again by the Schema file when the server is restarted)